# how can i have the high score in 1st in Tetris?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: unity]

I got some problem with my Tetris game on highscore, here's the game script

```
/// The width of the Grid...
public static int gridWidth = 10;

/// The weight of the Grid...
public static int gridWeight = 20;

/// The grid...
public static Transform[,] grid = new Transform[gridWidth, gridWeight];

public static bool startingAtLevelZero;
public static int startingLevel;

public int scoreOneLine = 50;
public int scoreTwoLine = 100;
public int scoreThreeLine = 400;
public int scoreFourLine = 1500;

public int currentLevel = 0;
private int numLinesCleared = 0;

public static float fallSpeed = 1.0f;

public AudioClip clearedLineSound;

public Text hud_score;
public Text hud_level;
public Text hud_lines;

private int numberOfRowsThisTurn = 0;

private AudioSource audioSource;

public static int currentScore = 0;

private GameObject previewTetromino;
private GameObject nextTetromino;

private bool gameStarted = false;
private int startingHighScore;

private int startingHighScore2;
private int startingHighScore3;

private Vector2 previewTetrominoPosition = new Vector2(-6.5f, 16);

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    currentScore = 0;

    hud_score.text = "0";

    currentLevel = startingLevel;

    hud_level.text = currentLevel.ToString();

    hud_lines.text = "0";

    SpawnNextTetromino();

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    startingHighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore");
    startingHighScore2 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore2");
    startingHighScore3 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore3");
}

void Update()
{
    UpdateScore();

    UpdateUI();

    UpdateLevel();

    UpdateSpeed();
}

void UpdateLevel()
{
    if ((startingAtLevelZero == true) || (startingAtLevelZero == false && numLinesCleared / 10 > startingLevel))
       currentLevel = numLinesCleared / 10;
    Debug.Log("current Level : " + currentLevel);
}

void UpdateSpeed()
{
    fallSpeed = 1.0f - ((float)currentLevel * 0.1f);
    Debug.Log("current Fall Speed : " + fallSpeed);
}

public void UpdateUI()
{
    hud_score.text = currentScore.ToString();
    hud_level.text = currentLevel.ToString();
    hud_lines.text = numLinesCleared.ToString();
}

public void UpdateScore()
{
    if (numberOfRowsThisTurn > 0)
    {
        if (numberOfRowsThisTurn == 1)
        {
            ClearedOneLine();
        }
        else if (numberOfRowsThisTurn == 2)
        {
            ClearedOneLine();
        }
        else if (numberOfRowsThisTurn == 3)
        {
            ClearedThreeLine();
        }
        else if (numberOfRowsThisTurn == 4)
        {
            ClearedFourLine();
        }
        numberOfRowsThisTurn = 0;

        PlayLineClearedSound();
    }
}

public void ClearedOneLine()
{
    currentScore += scoreOneLine + (currentLevel * 20);
    numLinesCleared++;
}

public void ClearedTwoLine()
{
    currentScore += scoreTwoLine + (currentLevel * 25);
    numLinesCleared += 2;
}

public void ClearedThreeLine()
{
    currentScore += scoreThreeLine + (currentLevel * 30);
    numLinesCleared += 3;
}

public void ClearedFourLine()
{
    currentScore += scoreFourLine + (currentLevel * 40);
    numLinesCleared += 4;
}

public void PlayLineClearedSound()
{
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(clearedLineSound);
}

public void UpdateHighScore()
{
    if (currentScore > startingHighScore)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore3", startingHighScore2);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore2", startingHighScore);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", currentScore);
    }
    else if (currentScore > startingHighScore2)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore3", startingHighScore2);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore2", currentScore);
    }
    else if (currentScore > startingHighScore3)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore3", currentScore);
    }
}

public bool CheckIsAboveGrid(Tetromino tetromino)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x)
    {
        foreach (Transform mino in tetromino.transform)
        {
            Vector2 pos = Round(mino.position);

            if (pos.y > gridWeight - 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public bool IsFullRowAt (int y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x)
    {
        if (grid [x, y] == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    numberOfRowsThisTurn++;

    return true;
}

public void DeleteMinoAt(int y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x)
    {
        Destroy(grid[x, y].gameObject);

        grid[x, y] = null;
    }
}

public void MoveRowDown (int y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x)
    {
        if (grid[x, y] != null)
        {
            grid[x,y -1] = grid[x, y];

            grid[x, y] = null;

            grid[x, y -1].position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
        }
    }
}

public void MoveAllRowsDown (int y)
{
    for (int i = y; i < gridWeight; ++i)
    {
        MoveRowDown(i);
    }
}

public void DeleteRow()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < gridWeight; ++y)
    {
        if (IsFullRowAt(y))
        {
            DeleteMinoAt(y);

            MoveAllRowsDown(y + 1);

            --y;
        }
    }
}
public void UpdateGrid (Tetromino tetromino)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < gridWeight; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x)
        {
            if (grid[x, y] != null)
            {
                if (grid[x,y].parent == tetromino.transform)
                {
                    grid[x, y] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (Transform mino in tetromino.transform)
    {
        Vector2 pos = Round(mino.position);

        if (pos.y < gridWeight)
        {
            grid[(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y] = mino;
        }
    }
}

public Transform GetTransformAtGridPosition (Vector2 pos)
{
    if (pos.y > gridWeight -1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return grid[(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y];
    }
}

public void SpawnNextTetromino()
{
    if (!gameStarted)
    {
        gameStarted = true;

        nextTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino(), typeof(GameObject)), new Vector2(5.0f, 20.0f), Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino(), typeof(GameObject)), previewTetrominoPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino>().enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        previewTetromino.transform.localPosition = new Vector2(5.0f, 20.0f);
        nextTetromino = previewTetromino;
        nextTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino>().enabled = true;

        previewTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino(), typeof(GameObject)), previewTetrominoPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        previewTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino>().enabled = false;
    }
}

public bool CheckIsInsideGrid (Vector2 pos)
{
    return ((int)pos.x >= 0 && (int)pos.x < gridWidth && (int)pos.y >= 0);
}

public Vector2 Round (Vector2 pos)
{
    return new Vector2(Mathf.Round(pos.x), Mathf.Round(pos.y));
}

string GetRandomTetromino()
{
    int randomTetromino = Random.Range(1, 8);

    string randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_T";

    switch (randomTetromino)
    {
        case 1:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_T";
            break;
        case 2:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_Long";
            break;
        case 3:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_Square";
            break;
        case 4:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_J";
            break;
        case 5:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_L";
            break;
        case 6:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_S";
            break;
        case 7:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/Tetromino_Z";
            break;
    }
    return randomTetrominoName;
}

public void GameOver()
{
    UpdateHighScore();

    Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
}
```

and here's the game menu script

```
public Text levelText;
public Text highScoreText;
public Text highScoreText2;
public Text highScoreText3;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    levelText.text = "0";

    highScoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore").ToString();
    highScoreText2.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore2").ToString();
    highScoreText3.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore3").ToString();
}

public void PlayGame()
{
    if (Game.startingLevel == 0)
        Game.startingAtLevelZero = true;
    else
        Game.startingAtLevelZero = false;

    Application.LoadLevel("tetris");
}

public void ChangedValue (float value)
{
    Game.startingLevel = (int)value;
    levelText.text = value.ToString();
}

public void LaunchGameMenu()
{
    Application.LoadLevel("tetris menu");
}
```

When I got 1120 score in the Tetris game, it shows up in 2nd score instead of 3rd or 1st ,when I got 720 score, it doesn't show up in 3rd score, when I score 1300 It shows up in 2nd and 1120 in 3rd, but not in 1st, can somehow help me what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried verifying that you have the correct `Text` assigned in the inspector? You may have the first highscore not assigned to `highScoreText`

Comment: @DekuDesu What do you mean?
i have the first high score text from the canvas to HighScoreText
and how can I assign this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have various typographical errors while typing the keys when accessing the player's `PlayerPrefs`. [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) is case-sensitive.

```cs
                                           ↓↓↓
startingHighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore");
startingHighScore2 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore2");
startingHighScore3 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore3");

...
                                            ↓↓↓
highScoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore").ToString();
```

Consider the use of the [`nameof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) command. The `nameof()` command allows you to treat a variable in-code as a string. This is SUPER helpful if you ever re-name the variable for example, the string will be renamed along with it. It also has the added bonus of giving you compilation errors if they are misspelled.

Example:

```cs
public Text levelText;
public Text highScoreText;
public Text highScoreText2;
public Text highScoreText3;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    levelText.text = "0";

    highScoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(nameof(highScoreText)).ToString();
    highScoreText2.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(nameof(highScoreText2)).ToString();
    highScoreText3.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(nameof(highScoreText3)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, but when I tested I and making some scores. it only shows 0 in every score board whenever I playing the game and I keep getting he error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object TetrisMenu.Start () (at Assets/Resources/TetrisMenu.cs:16)

Comment: Make sure that `highScoreText`, `highScoreText2`, `highScoreText3` are properly assigned in the inspector. As a last resort basis you can always use regular `string`s again for the keys, just be careful not to transpose the keys so that they're assigning different values.

Comment: but I have the first score text that one which shows points assigned to the inspector in the game script, and the others score text are also there. I don't know what is wrong

Comment: I recommend stepping through your code step-by-step and seeing where any problems are encountered. That should give you more information than I can provide.

Comment: but I don't know what the problem is, whenever I pressing on nulloeferenceexception, it keep sending me to
void Start()
    {
        levelText.text = "0";

        highScoreText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(nameof(highScoreText)).ToString();
        highScoreText2.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(nameof(highScoreText2)).ToString();
        highScoreText3.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(nameof(highScoreText3)).ToString();
    }

Comment: Check out [this post covering `NullReferenceExceptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) it might be able to assist you.

Comment: yet I still don't know how to do it and what I should do. I been looking through tutorials about Tetris on YouTube and did what it actually did.

Comment: where can I show you the photos of my code of the inspector and editor to you?